# Does it make sense to calculate relative ratios of items from different scales when I need to normalize the result?

Tags: average, means, ratio

Let's say I have two different scales for size, where the first (A) is 0-10 and the other (B) is 0-1000. Then I will use each to measure (relative) sizes of products for which I know the number of flaws/defects.
Now I get two sets of results:

- A (sizes and product defects): 5 (2 defects), 8 (3 defects), 2 (1 defect)
- B (sizes and product defects): 480 (2 defects), 600 (2 defects), 300 (1 defect)

I would like to express the average defect rate but because the scales are different, A would look terribly defective while B would look almost perfect if both were compared as No of defects / size unit.

I was wondering, would working with averages be a possible solution here? I mean:

- For A, average size is 5. The ratio of individual sizes to the average would be 1, 0.63 and 2.5
- For B, average size is 460, and ratios would be: 0.95, 0.76 and 1.53

Now, if I add the relative sizes, I get 4.1 for A and 3.3 for B. And finally, calculating the defect ratios:

- 0.68 for A
- 0.66 for B

This sounds right because they are virtually the same.

Is this a better approach than simply calculating Defect/ number of products? (so 6/3 and 5/3 in this example)?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You have given 2 wrong ways to Calculate average defect rate. You have to compare the number of defective Items with the total number of Items , not with the Size of the items. When X out of 1000 trucks (Size=10000) are defective & Y out of 100 cycles (Size=10) are defective , we should check X/1000 & Y/100 , not giving weightage to Size. That weightage will enter when we Put these 2 Items together to calculate the Over-all **"Size-weighted"** defect rate , not otherwise !

Comment: @Prem: Sorry, I meant size-weighted, or rather defect rate per size unit. Defect/total number of items does not help much, this weighted way shows a bit better results. This is for a case when the size is arbitrary chosen because the item is abstract but you still can tell whether it is bigger or smaller then another item. EDIT: This is not meant to be AVERAGE defect rate, but defect rate per size/unit

Comment: Even when we want the Over-all **"Size-weighted"** defect rate , it is still calculated with "the number of defective Items" versus "the total number of Items" , with each Item being weighted with the Size. Without involving the total number of Items , it is not defect rate. It will not be between 0% & 100%. It can exceed 100% which is invalid & weird.